# NoSuchMethodError io.netty.util.AsciiString.cached

Tags: java, vert.x, vertx-httpclient

I am new to Java and have jumped into maintaining an existing software system written in Java which makes use of Vertx.io . When I call the Vertx web client .get() method, I get an error with the netty package. I have googled for the error, but cannot find anything. Can someone suggest what I am doing wrong?

Here is the calling code:

```
WebClient client = WebClient.create(vertx);
client
    .get(port, server, path)
    .timeout(5000)
    .send(ar -> {
        if (ar.succeeded()) {
            ...
```

Here is the exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.netty.util.AsciiString.cached(Ljava/lang/String;)Lio/netty/util/AsciiString;
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpHeaderValues.<clinit>(HttpHeaderValues.java:28)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpUtil.<clinit>(HttpUtil.java:41)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http.EmptyHttpHeaders.<clinit>(EmptyHttpHeaders.java:29)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpHeaders.<clinit>(HttpHeaders.java:49)
    at io.vertx.core.http.HttpHeaders.createOptimized(HttpHeaders.java:331)
    at io.vertx.core.http.HttpHeaders.<clinit>(HttpHeaders.java:31)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.client.impl.HttpRequestImpl.<init>(HttpRequestImpl.java:70)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.client.impl.HttpRequestImpl.<init>(HttpRequestImpl.java:54)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.client.impl.WebClientImpl.request(WebClientImpl.java:50)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.client.impl.WebClientImpl.get(WebClientImpl.java:50)
    at ... my calling class
```

Comment: Is the netty library deployed in your execution environment? Is it the exact same version as the one you used to build the application?

Comment: As @JimGarrison suggests, I believe you're using an older Netty version. Check you project setup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that the issue was caused by another Vertx library (vertx-lang-ceylon) that I had added as a dependency for use with Chime to do scheduling. The version was older than the other vertx libraries and this seemed to have introduced the issue.

To fix, I edited my build.gradle file and changed

```
compile 'io.vertx:vertx-lang-ceylon:3.4.1'
```

to

```
compile 'io.vertx:vertx-lang-ceylon:3.5.0'
```

And that solved the issue.